# Rounded boxes with text inside in beamer

Tags: pdflatex

I want to have several texts in latex which are boxed in a circle or more in a rounded box.
I tried to use:

```
\pgfnodecircle{Node1}[stroke]{\pgfxy(1,1)}{0.5cm}
\pgfnodecircle{Node2}[strokel]{\pgfxy(3,0.5)}{0.25cm}
\pgfnodecircle{Node3}[fill]{\pgfxy(5,1)}{0.25cm}  
\pgfnodeconnline{Node1}{Node2}  
\pgfnodeconnline{Node2}{Node3}
```

but this `\pgfnodecircle` command does not allow me to write text inside the nodecircle.
I could have added text with `\pgfnodebox` but I really want the text to be surrounded by rounded boxes and not by rectangular boxes.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about LaTeX

Answer (score 18):

maybe you want the block environments: block, theorem, proof, and example? You can then find a Beamer style to make them rounded.

```
\begin{block}{Block title}
text here
\end{block}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for via google :-) I forgot the name of the command.

Answer (score 5):

The commands `\ovalbox` and `\Ovalbox` defined package *fancybox* might help:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\begin{document}
  \ovalbox{hello}
  \Ovalbox{world}
  bye
  \doublebox{important}
\end{document}
```

Please have a look at the [documentation of the fancybox package](ftp://ctan.tug.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancybox/fancybox.pdf) for more details.

Other interesting commands: `\boxed` defined in the *amsmath* package and `\shabox` defined in the *shadow* package.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
\setbeamercolor{uppercolgreen}{fg=white,bg=green!35}
\setbeamercolor{lowercolgreen}{fg=black,bg=green!10}
...
\begin{beamerboxesrounded}[upper=uppercolgreen,lower=lowercolgreen,shadow=true]
{Definition - What is A:} 
$A:= 2 + 5$.
\end{beamerboxesrounded}
```